# Calculating a one-sided limit

Tags: limits

We have the following limit to calculate $$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} t^{(t^a)}$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

So logically speaking, you could say that the limit becomes $t^0$ which is always $1$ no matter how small $t$ becomes. But how can you mathematically write that? Intuitively the concepts clicks with me.

Comment: Hint - "a" is a constant, "t" is the only variable

Comment: The reason it might not be zero is that $t^n$ goes to zero and $t^0$ is 1.

Comment: @MaxW Yeah, I realized that, but I still don't see how this limit is anything other than zero.

Comment: This is cheating but $.001^{.001} = .993...$ so the limit is probably 1.  just need to figure out why.

Comment: I'm guessing $1$ if $a>0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Try letting $x=t^a$, so that $t^{(t^a)}=x^{x/a}=(x^x)^{1/a}$. If $a>0$, we're taking the limit as $x\downarrow0$; if $a<0$, we're taking the limit as $x\to\infty$. $a=0$ is it's own special case.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, that helps my understanding. But how would you explain that in ma mathematically sound way?